# S3 file as input to PDFBox

Tags: java, amazon-s3, pdfbox

I have tried Apache PDFBox to extract content from PDF files, which worked fine when I am just extracting a local PDF.

But the actual input PDFs that I want to parse are in S3 bucket.

I can read the S3 object using the below code,

```
final AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2).withCredentials(awsCredentailsService()).build();
        S3Object object = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));

        InputStream ins = object.getObjectContent();
```

But I am not able to figure out how to pass this file to PDFBox to get the content. The PDFBox load() method expects a File object. I tried passing the input stream (ins) obtained above from S3Object but it doesn't accept - compile error.

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);
```

Please help.

Comment: Download the file to local disk, then point PDFBox to the file.

Comment: *"I tried passing the input stream (ins) obtained above from S3Object but it doesn't accept"* - how did you try?

Comment: PDDocument.load() does accept an InputStream. What version are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest version - 2.0.18.

Comment: Thanks Tilman Hausherr.. Yes the PDFBox load() method does accept inputstream...

Answer (score 2):

Just passed the inputStream to load method. It works !

```
S3Object object = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(s3BucketName, key));
InputStream ins = object.getObjectContent();

PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(ins);
```

Comment: 1) don't forget to close your inputStream, 2) I wonder why this didn't work before. 3) 2.0.19 has been released :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the newer version, you need to use `Loader`. So your code will be something like this:

```
S3Object s3object = amazonS3Client.getObject(BUCKET_NAME, fileName);
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = s3object.getObjectContent();
PDDocument doc = Loader.loadPDF(is);
```

Comment: The javadoc doesn't mention a `ByteArrayInputStream`, or am I missing something? If it is, then you should add a cast. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3ObjectInputStream.html